# Trying to add active class to thumbnail Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, highlight

I have a Jquery function that slideToggles hidden divs when a corresponding thumbnail is clicked. I want to add an "active" class to highlight the thumbnail when the div is visible. It gets complicated because the visible div can be closed by clicking the corresponding thumbnail, clicking a different thumbnail, or clicking a "close" button inside the div. Is there a way to add this functionality into this function? Or should I try creating a new one? Here's the function:

```
 var prev = null;
function toggleDiv(e) {
  var divToToggle = $( $(this).find("a").attr('href') );
  if (prev && (!prev.is($(this)))) { //switch
    var prevDiv = $( prev.find("a").attr('href') );
    var divs = divToToggle.add(prevDiv); //add prevDiv into collection
    divs.slideToggle("slow"); //slideToggle all in collection
    prev = $(this);
  } else { //show/hide
    prev = divToToggle[0].style.display == 'block' ? null : $(this);
    divToToggle.slideToggle("slow");
  }
  return false;
}
$(".press").click(toggleDiv);
```

The thumbnails and close buttons have a class of ".press", with an anchor tag inside that points to the ID of the divs.

Update: Here's a basic codepen example of what I'm doing:
[codepen.io/nathans000/pen/OpZqGP](http://codepen.io/nathans000/pen/OpZqGP)

Comment: It would help if you gave us a demo of what you have so far, anything you've tried, and what the specific behavior you want to achieve is (based off of the demo). See how to create a [mcve]. Seeing it in action and your HTML structure would help us give you a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info Michael! Here's a demo in codepen:
http://codepen.io/nathans000/pen/OpZqGP
I basically just want to add an active class to the thumbnails so I can style them when their corresponding div is visible. Thanks! Nathan

Comment: You can have some `data-something` attribute in the thumbnails, whose content is the id of the toggling div. Inside your function you can select it like `$('div[data-something="id"]').removeClass('active');`. Same idea could be done with classes or ids. You have the previously active id inside `prev` variable so you can do that. Try it and if you cant do it post your code and we will help you further

Comment: Thanks guys! I finally got it to work. The syntax for passing a variable into the "data-something" value took me forever to figure out. It requires 2 sets of quotes:
    $('div[data-click = "'+thumbHL+'"]').addClass('active-thumb');
where thumbHL is the target href and "data-click" attribute.

Comment: I appreciate the help